# What is the line between a strawman and a genuine criticism?

Tags: fallacies

There is a very fine-line between strawman and genuine criticism. How do you find the line?

In recent debates about abolishing the police, a common counterargument is "Do you want criminals running free? That's what you'll get if you get rid of the police". This could also be seen as genuine criticism or a strawman.

How do you tell the difference in this case or any other case?

Comment: You tell it by checking the [definition of strawman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man): was the original argument replaced by a simplified one which is easier to refute? It is hard to tell what sort of answer you expect beyond that. And what is the point exactly? If you consider the proposed refutation a strawman simply present the intended argument that it does not address.

Answer (score 2):

"Do you want criminals running free? That's what you'll get if you get rid of the police". That's not a straw man at all. If someone wants to abolish the police, it's a fair and good criticism.

But if someone didn't suggest at all to get rid of the police - say I said "We should stop racists from entering the police force" and you reply "You want to get rid of the police? Criminals will be running free!" you combined an incorrect claim of what I asked for, and a refutation of the claim that I never made. And *that* is the definition of a straw man.

Comment: what if they want to abolish the police and replace the police with something else?